# Not able to insert csv data into mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have one csv file that have so many fields but interested in only 5. We picked them up using pandas and now want to insert into mysql table.

This is the logic for  same.

Table strucure:

```
order_execution_time,text,YES,"",,""
symbol,text,YES,"",,""
trade_type,text,YES,"",,""
price,double,YES,"",,""
quantity,int,YES,"",,""
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from mysql.connector import Error
from src.config.python_mysql_config import get_connection

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\91720\\Downloads\\tradebook-VT0986.csv", usecols = ['order_execution_time', 'symbol', 'trade_type', 'price', 'quantity'])

try:
    conn = get_connection()
    if conn.is_connected():
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select database();")
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        print("You're connected to database: ", record)

        #loop through the data frame
        for i,row in df.iterrows():
            #here %S means string values
            sql = "INSERT INTO trades (symbol, order_execution_time, trade_type, price, quantity) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%d,%f)"
            cursor.execute(sql, tuple(row))
            print("Record inserted")
            # the connection is not auto committed by default, so we must commit to save our changes
            conn.commit()
except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
```

It is throwing me this error:

```
Error while connecting to MySQL Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

How to get it resolve?

Comment: You need to extract just the columns of the pandas table that you want to insert, you can't use `tuple(row)` because that includes other columns that aren't being inserted.

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this with your own loop instead of `df.to_sql()`?

Comment: extracting only interested ones.. usecols = ['order_execution_time', 'symbol', 'trade_type', 'price', 'quantity'])